# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have read an image to a numpy array. I do some transformations on each pixel and then I need to check what the resulting pixel coordinates are. If they are negative, x coordinate is greater than num of rows in image or y coordinate is greater then number of columns in image I need to make appropriate manipulations.

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png')
rows,columns,ch = np.shape(image)

for c in range(ch):
    for px in range(0,rows):
        for py in range(0,columns):
            ip_vector = np.array([px,py])
            ip_vector.shape=(2,1)
            op_vector = np.dot(trans_array,ip_vector)
            op_vector=np.around(op_vector)
            [px_dash,py_dash]=op_vector
            if px_dash >= 0 and px_dash < rows and py_dash >= 0 and py_dash<columns:
                new_image[px_dash,py_dash,c]=image[px,py,c]
```

> new_image[px_dash,py_dash,c]=image[px,py,c]
>   IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

I tried

```
image = image.astype(int)
new_image = new_image.astype(int)
```

and error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ouput of np.around() is of type `float`. You can't use floats for indexing arrays.
Convert the output and it should work:

```
new_image[int(px_dash),int(py_dash),c] = image[px,py,c]
```